# Create an image stream in python , similar to cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, imagestream

I access a camera (Infratec Image IR 8310 which is a high-end infrared camera) using an SDK which internally uses a callback function to access the single frames.

I now want to publish these images using some kind of stream, such that I can access this stream for example with cv2.VideoCapture(0) or similar functions.
Yet however, when I run the SDK, cv2.VideoCapture will not recognize it as stream, I can only access my webcam and snap-camera :-D

I would be happy about ever hint.
Cheers,
Max

Comment: to stream you have to create server - and `cv2` doesn't have function to create server. Somewhere on internet there is example how to use Python web framework `Flask` to send stream of `mjpeg` (motion-jpeg) from `cv2` or Raspberry webcam.

Comment: in question you should add your code and what camera you use. And what SDK you use. And put it in question, not in comment - more people will see it.

Comment: [Flask Video Streaming Revisited](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited)

Comment: some cameras my send stream in `RTSP` stream and `cv2` can read it `cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://address_ip")`. And some cameras can work with programs which create virtual camera in system and then you can access them with next number `cv2.VideoCapture(1)` or on Linux `cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video1")`

Comment: Hi Furas, thx. I added the camera type. The code is quite large as it is implemented rather low level, I don't think that makes sense ;-)  However I will check out you link, thank you